# plugins.legend.align are incompatible types typescript chartjs

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I have something like this in my options object

```
const options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      align: 'end',
    }
  }
}
```

According to Chartjs [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html), align accepts 3 values:

- start
- center
- end

The alignment works fine, I am getting the desired result but typescript is complaining that the type of align should be 'start', 'center' or 'end' and not a string.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type ' "end" | "start" | "center" | undefined '
```

Diving in into Chartjs type definition, I see

```
export interface LegendOptions<TType extends ChartType> {
  ....
  /**
   * Alignment of the legend.
   * @default 'center'
   */
  align: 'start' | 'center' | 'end';

}
```

If I change align to a type of string. The typescript error goes away but I shouldn't be doing it.

Any ideas / comments / suggestions is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Cant seem to reproduce it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQBYENYBo5QKYDmwAzjHlOgEYA2exOamMyEAdgGbAECuFMwbBhlgARdDHRwAvnHZQIIOAHIAxsJgA6AFbElAbgBQBlW1JwQATzESAvHADaARiwAmLAGYAuoZOszl63RiPBhiOBskABNxIJDiAC4HBGiJRICYqU8caio8agSHJUclLCUXEqV3CoAWJU9pQ2NTeAIQlg4ucLgACgBKRMZYds4ePgFWAB4lSkwlAD5whYQDOFXcEN5WRBW13d2YCzA8ROnZrB29vZT0NKsY4NDzy8uIMH5TROXn77gwam4iH5Phcft9aK1WJFgaCYWt0NQuKwTnhIUoQbDdlJ0TCsbDcc98assUA

Comment: Give me a minute please

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-lewin-srjyy?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue seems to be within the `react-chartjs-2` lib.

If you switch to the barebone version of chart.js you wont have this issue:https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-curie-eyxrr?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2):

Try add `as cons`.

```
align: 'center' as const
```

Found this solution in [their repo](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/1009)

Comment: This works for me!